# elem1.Location as LocationPoint).Point is returning null in the below code. Can anyone help me on this?

Tags: c#, lambda, revit-api

The code appears to aim at selecting multiple text elements and then arranging them with a specific horizontal distance between them.

```
IList<Reference> selectedRefs = uiDoc.Selection.PickObjects(ObjectType.Element,"Select text instances");

    if (selectedRefs.Count < 2)
    {
                    TaskDialog.Show("Error", "Select at least two text instances.");
                    return Result.Cancelled;
    }

                // Calculate the desired equal horizontal distance between text instances
    double desiredHorizontalDistance = 50.0; // Change this value as needed

    using (Transaction tx = new Transaction(doc, "Move Text "))
    {
      tx.Start();

                    // Sort selected text instances by their X-coordinates
      List<Element> selectedTextInstances = new List<Element>();
      foreach (Reference reference in selectedRefs)
      {
       Element textElement = doc.GetElement(reference);
       selectedTextInstances.Add(textElement);
      }

      selectedTextInstances.Sort((elem1, elem2) =>
      {
       XYZ point1 = (elem1.Location as LocationPoint).Point;
       //XYZ point1 = elem1.Coord;
       XYZ point2 = (elem2.Location as LocationPoint).Point;
       return point1.X.CompareTo(point2.X);
       });}
```

Comment: Well that would happen if either `elem1.Location` is null, or if it's not a `LocationPoint`. I suggest you use the debugger to find out which, as a starting point.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please keep the question title short and pertinent.

Answer (score 1):

The `Location` property of a text element can consist of multiple points, depending on the text alignment settings. Therefore, the property value cannot be represented in either `LocationPoint` or `LocationCurve`. Therefore, unfortunately, the Revit API does not provide any possibility to either read or write this property.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use the midpoint of the elements with `LocationCurve` locations as a surrogate for the `LocationPoint`. Something like this:

```csharp
    XYZ point1 = (elem1.Location is LocationCurve locationCurve)
       ? (locationCurve.Curve.GetEndPoint(0) + locationCurve.Curve.GetEndPoint(1)) / 2.0
       : (elem1.Location as LocationPoint)?.Point;
```

Alternatively, the one of the endpoints on their own might be enough for your use case.